# java.lang.AbstractMethodError,RESTFul Web service

Tags: eclipse

I have tried to build a sample RESTFul web service application  using jersey jars. But  facing the following mentioned error.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>WebserviceSample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Java Web service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>repair</param-value>

        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Java Web service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**repair.java**

```
package repair;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

//annotations

@Path("/mobileRepair")
public class Repair {

    @GET
    // getting query from user
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    // Consumer request as XML
    public String sayHello() {
        String response = "<?xml version='1.0'><CustomerName><CustomerId>Hello Karthik</CustomerId></CustomerName>";
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could specify how it should behave, ie. what should your piece of code do?

Comment: How would someone need to set up Glassfish to replicate this? Did you do anything special? Nothing in this question actually mentions Eclipse.

Comment: I just followed a video in youtube as mentioned  below https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfEUDAHgrGQ .

Comment: I just followed a video in youtube as mentioned  below https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfEUDAHgrGQ .Actually I'm just trying to access the class and get a hard coded response through URI through the above menioned repair.java